# How to fetch all URLs of a wordpress site by typing it's domain name

Tags: wordpress, api, codeigniter

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project and I've to fetch All URLs of `WordPress` domain name. Like when a user enters `www.example.com` then the system will give me an array of all page and post URLs of that site.

Comment: This is way too broad and really lacks some individual initiative.

Comment: I've to  do it any idea

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```php
$url = file_get_contents('https://example.com');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($url);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$myArray = array();
foreach ($links as $link){
    $myArray[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```